# gRPC ClientAsyncWriter Finish

Tags: c++, grpc

According to the documentation of AsyncWriter `finish()` s*hould not be used concurrently with other operations.* Which operations are meant here? Does it mean that if I put read tag to the completion queue I am not allowed to call `finish` until the tag is returned by the queue? Then as far as I understand in order to interrupt execution, I have to call `tryCancel` on the client's context, and as soon as the read tag is consumed I am allowed to send finish tag. Or after calling `tryCancel` it is not required to call `finish`?